# How to generate total size of files from each unique source in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a large number of directories which each contain files with the format

```
unimportant_data_here_source_date.gz
```

I want to calculate how much data came from each source.  That means figuring out unique sources in any sub directory, then calculating the sum of the size of all files with that unique source.

Can anyone help me figure out the command to do this?  My bash-foo is not up to the task it seems.  The approach I started with seemed way to complicated, I feel like there must be an easier approach.

Comment: Does it absolutely have to be bash, or could it be perl?

Comment: Show what you have so far

Comment: `find -name '*.gz' -exec gzip -ql '{}' \+`

Comment: if a source for your data is dumping into the same directory, why not use `du -sk /some/directory/location/here` ? You can scrape the numeric part of the output with awk and add them up as you please.